# Pandas, фильтрация необходимых данных

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, фильтрация

Имеется код

```
In [104]: import requests

In [105]: r = requests.get('https://api.kucoin.com/v1/open/tick')

In [108]: df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['data']).sort_values(['symbol'])

In [109]: df
Out[109]:
           buy        change  changeRate coinType coinTypePair       datetime  feeRate       high  lastDealPrice  \
93    0.000001  2.000000e-08      0.0165     ACAT          BTC  1519824458000    0.001   0.000001       0.000001
94    0.000015  1.000000e-06      0.0714     ACAT          ETH  1519824458000    0.001   0.000017       0.000015
95    0.000103  1.100000e-05      0.1196     ACAT          NEO  1519824458000    0.001   0.000139       0.000103
```

Я хочу выдернуть некоторые строки, например, по ключу coinTypePair взять NEO, но напечатать данные этих строк из столбца buy.
Делая простой цикл, я могу получить нужные мне строки, но напечатать при этом только данные того самого столбца coinTypePair.

Comment: вы хотите вывести значения только одного столбца для найденных строк? Можете привести пример того что вы хотите получить на выходе, скажем для двух строк?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пример:

```py
In [179]: df.loc[df['coinTypePair'].isin(['NEO']), ['buy']]
Out[179]:
          buy
95   0.000095
135  8.764146
83   0.000621
124  0.000180
100  0.009362
140  0.060193
15   0.000514
..        ...
162  0.010056
108  0.001623
187  0.168654
92   0.001380
34   0.000175
37   0.001095
25   0.000958

[17 rows x 1 columns]
```

В виде строки (без индекса):

```py
In [180]: out = df.loc[df['coinTypePair'].isin(['NEO']), ['buy']].to_string(index=False)

In [181]: print(out)
buy
0.000095
8.764146
0.000621
0.000180
0.009362
0.060193
0.000514
0.290003
1.533000
0.020813
0.010056
0.001623
0.168654
0.001380
0.000175
0.001095
0.000958
```

В виде строки (без индекса и без наименования столбца):

```py
In [182]: out = df.loc[df['coinTypePair'].isin(['NEO']), ['buy']].to_string(index=False, header=None)

In [183]: print(out)
0.000095
8.764146
0.000621
0.000180
0.009362
0.060193
0.000514
0.290003
1.533000
0.020813
0.010056
0.001623
0.168654
0.001380
0.000175
0.001095
0.000958
```